# ApplicationInsights - prevent samples of quick successful requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights, .net-4.8

I have an application hooked up to application insights and we have decent amount of requests. The vast majority are sub 80ms but we have a few which are >300ms.
The issue i have is that when we want to investiagte the longer queries we find we don't have samples for them as thw quick running requests have filled up the sample quota.

What I want to be able to do is prevent/restrict quick successful requests from be included in the samples but remain as part of the overall metrics of requests.

I've tried a custom ITelemetryProcessor to exclude the quick calls but they are also no longer visiable on the metric count so i have no idea of if they are called.

I've tried an ITelemetryInitializer and set the request.ProactiveSamplingDecision = SamplingDecision.SampledOut but this removes it from the metrics as well.

The application uses C# .Net 4.8 (Full Framework)

Has anyone done something similar or can help me achieve what i'm looking to do?

Code for TelemetryInitializer:

```
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        // Is this a TrackRequest() ?
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;

        if (requestTelemetry.Success == true && requestTelemetry.Duration.TotalMilliseconds < 100)
        {
            requestTelemetry.ProactiveSamplingDecision = SamplingDecision.SampledOut;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the TelementryFilter:

```
public class SuccessfulTelementryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }        
    
    public SuccessfulTelementryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }
    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as RequestTelemetry;

        if (request != null && request.Success == true && request.Duration.Milliseconds < 100)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Andy, can you please share the piece of code that which you tired?

Comment: @SureshChikkam I've added my code.

Comment: may be the issues is due to the interaction between proactive sampling decisions and custom processors. When you set `requestTelemetry.ProactiveSamplingDecision = SamplingDecision.SampledOut`, it effectively removes the telemetry item from all metrics and samples.

Comment: Instead of that why can't you use the `IRequestTelemetry.ProactiveSamplingEligibility` property to prevent sampling without excluding it from the metrics. @Andy

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `MyTelemetryInitializer`, setting `ProactiveSamplingDecision` to `SamplingDecision.SampledOut` will indeed exclude the telemetry item from the overall metrics, which is why you can't see them in the metrics. Instead, you can use the `IRequestTelemetry.ProactiveSamplingEligibility` property to prevent sampling without excluding it from the metrics.

Try this alternative approach, check below.

- Create a custom telemetry type that extends the `RequestTelemetry` class and adds a custom property for exclusion.

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;

public class CustomRequestTelemetry : RequestTelemetry
{
    public bool ExcludeFromSampling { get; set; }
}
```

- Filter out telemetry items based on the `ExcludeFromSampling` property.

```cs
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is CustomRequestTelemetry customRequestTelemetry)
        {
            if (customRequestTelemetry.Success == true && customRequestTelemetry.Duration.TotalMilliseconds < 100)
            {
                customRequestTelemetry.ExcludeFromSampling = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- The custom telemetry processor should check this property and prevent telemetry items from being sampled.

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

public class SuccessfulTelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public SuccessfulTelemetryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (item is CustomRequestTelemetry customRequestTelemetry && customRequestTelemetry.ExcludeFromSampling)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

- Register your custom telemetry initializer and telemetry processor in your Application Insights configuration.

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
    .Use((next) => new SuccessfulTelemetryFilter(next))
    .Build();

TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder
    .Use((next) => new MyTelemetryInitializer(next))
    .Build();
```

Filtered response:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the property on my RequestTelementry. Is there another package I need to install?

Comment: If I return from the ITelemetryProcessor won't the telementry be excluded from Application Insights completly and not show against the metrics?

My first approach was to do this but the telementry request was not sent to application insights so it looks like that endpoint is never called.

Comment: Yes @Andy, telemetry item will be excluded from Application Insights entirely, including the metrics. change your sampling strategy Instead of completely excluding these quick requests, you can reduce the sampling rate for them.

Comment: Also RequestTelemetry is a sealed class so cannot be inherited from.

Comment: do you know how I can change the sampling strategy for paticular requests? As it looks like it's an all or nothing kind of thing.